# New German irregular verbs. Are there any?

Tags: verb, history, curiosity

New verbs in English are invariably regular. *Sneak*, an old verb in English dating from the 16th century, is one of the very few that have, at least in some parts of the world, become irregular  (with *snuck* now competing with *sneaked*), and only in the last 100 years.

Are there any truly new arrivals (by which I mean only to exclude established verbs with new prefix uses) of irregular or strong verbs in German?

Comment: According to Wiktionary, "snuck" was formed by analogy with "struck". Similarly "dove" (less common) was formed (presumably) by analogy with "drove". The Old English *snican* is also strong but with a different vowel change, so it was regularized and then deregularized  The point is that the overall trend is toward regularization, with exceptions being due to similarities with common irregular verbs.

Comment: @RDBury Interesting. Burchfield, in Fowler's Modern English Usage (Oxford Press) says, "Meanwhile, no one has satisfactorily accounted for the origin of *snuck*: there is no other verb in the language with the infinitive *-eek* or *-eak* and pa.t. *-uck*. Consider the following verbs: *creak, freak, leak, peak, peek, reek, seek, squeak, streak, wreak,,* also *shriek*. None of them has shown any sign of following the path of *sneak* by acquiring a new pa.t. form.

Comment: @ user02814 If I may say so, it very much sounds to me that the principle behind giving rise to the *sneak-snuck* combination is also vowel gradation: *stick-stuck*, *tik-tok*, *click-clock*, *sneak-snuck*?

Comment: I have never heard "snuck" (or "dove") used in British English - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/snuck

Comment: Getting a bit away from the point, but fwiw they're ("snuck" - although I think I'd have spelt it "snook", personally - and "dove") my default past tense forms for those verbs (32 y/o, lived in NW England from birth until early 20s).

Comment: 'snuck' is American-English (regional, southern) slang (think Mark Twain), not British-English. Similarly 'thunk' for 'thought', 'lay' for 'lie', 'warnt' for 'wasn't/weren't', 'done gone' instead of 'went' or 'has gone'. Answers might want to consider how AmE and BrE branched away from each other since the 16th century.

Comment: @smci https://youtu.be/PJVNzwTnfbk

Comment: In English, new irregular verbs may be formed by combining with old irregular verbs.  So *rerun, reran* dates only to 1804 in the *Oxford English Dictionary*.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just like in English, this section of grammar in German has hardly experienced any substantial additions or expansion for a long time now as the principles that brought about these irregular verbs were only actively applied in the very early days of the Germanic languages. There is the, somewhat funny, [Gesellschaft zur Stärkung der Verben](https://neutsch.org/Startseite) (Society for the Irregularisation of Verbs) trying to account for the lack of development here.

Similarly to *sneak/sneaked* vs. *sneak/snuck*, the only comparative German counterpart I can think of right now is ***winken/winkte/gewinkt*** vs. ***winken/(wunk)/gewunken*** (to wave) which is most likely to enter eventually into generally accepted usage (if it hasn’t already) to coexist then with the regular version.

Apart from this more or less unique new creation and addition, at times you could hear mix-ups of largely homophonic verbs because of the ignorance of possible differences:

- ***hängen/hing/gehangen*** vs. ***hängen/hängte/gehängt***: The former is the intransitive version of *hängen*; the latter is the transitive one. So, they differ in that you would either *have something/be hanging* (*hing*) or *make something hanging* (*hängte*).
- ***leiden/litt/gelitten*** vs. ***leiten/leitete/geleitet***: Ever so often, mathematicians ignore the origin of the word *ableiten* (to differentiate) and say things like *abgelitten.* I would say this is just a spleen with various individuals coming from mathematical professions because they likely have never considered the possibility of a lapse of memory here.
- ***genießen/genoss/genossen*** vs. ***niesen/nieste/geniest***: By the spur of the moment, at times people say (jokingly) *genossen* (*enjoyed*) instead of *geniest* (*sneezed*).
- ***schleifen/schliff/geschliffen*** vs. ***schleifen/schleifte/geschleift***: Sometimes people mix up the former (meaning *to hone,* e.g. a piece of metal) with the latter (meaning *to slight,* e.g., a fortress).

It is also quite often the case that the past participle in German is produced erroneously while the main point to look at here is the actual intention of using one version or the other, i.e. by state or progression of the action implied by the verb.

Although being lexicalised with only one, many regular verbs are occasionally used with a different past participle in German. For example, ***abgeschaltet*** vs. ***abgeschalten*** (to switch off [e.g. the television]) stems from the regular verb *schalten* which is conjugated with either of the two auxiliary verbs in German (*sein/haben*). It should be conjugated accordingly as follows:

> Der Fernseher ist abgeschaltet.
> Der Fernseher hat abgeschaltet.

There is also the tendency to use:

> *Der Fernseher ist abgeschalten.

This stems in all likelihood from the non-obvious difference in usage of the auxiliary verbs with irregular verbs: *ist gesprungen* / *hat gestanden* / *hat gesprochen* / *hat geschwiegen* / *ist geschritten* / *ist gelaufen.*

In general, making use of the vowel gradation (Ablautreihe) is so much easier to achieve physiopsychologically while speaking that one could also quite often hear new *Starke Verben* being produced, that is new irregular verbs created ad-hoc.

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE and thank you for your answer. I edited it quite a bit because I found it difficult to extract what you were aiming at and some sentences were very convoluted. Please check whether everything is still according to your intentions.

Comment: The _schleifte/geschleift_ form also has the more common meaning of "to drag".

Comment: It might be useful to give a yas/no answer at the top.

Comment: @ user46563 Welcome! How wonderful for me to return from work to find such a surprising and comprehensive answer! *winken* (!). Great!

Comment: @ user02814 Thank you. I am glad my answer has been informative to you.

Comment: I would like to challenge the claim contained in "at times people say (jokingly) genossen (*enjoyed*) instead of geniest (*sneezed*)", *viz.*, that "genossen" is just a joke. What's the basis for this challenge? Several Swiss-German dialects -- and especially Walliser-Deutsch (which is mostly pure Mittelhochdeutsch with a few Althochdeutsch components thrown in for good measure) -- definitely use "ernosse'" and "g'nosse'" as the past participle of "niesen". Thus, "genossen" in Neuhochdeutsch may actually be a proper hold-over from older locutions rather than just a joke.

Comment: "abgeschalten"? Really? Never heard that ...

Comment: @Hagen I use it all the time. It only feels wrong when thinking longer about it.

Comment: I have used "abgelitten" in the mathematical term when I was studying (decades ago), and always as a little pun. Most native-speaking people either didn't notice at all, or if they did, they seemed to get it.

Comment: Abwiegen vs abwägen is being mixed up so often these days; it still makes me cringe..

Comment: Very nice pointing out cases like «abgeschalten». A similar case to «gewunken» is «abgestummen». A case more similar to “snuck” would be the unetymological preterite «frug».

Comment: The pun with “abgelitten” - as I have heard it - was to emphasise that the computation of the particular derivative in question was rather painful. But it’s not very common I’d say.

Comment: Note that "abgeschalten", or the base form "geschalten", "eingeschalten" and so on, seems to be commonly used in Austria, at least in some parts of the country. That's where I heard it - an Austrian company is one of our customers in building automation and they say it a lot. Another word they taught me which I never heard of before is Stiegenhausschaltung (the standard German term is Treppenhausschaltung), i.e. a light that is switched on when pressing the button and stays on for some time before switching off again. Then it's ausgeschalten.

Comment: How does one slight a fortress?

Comment: @Kyralessa: See [Wiktionary, Meaning 5](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slight#Verb).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft The page has the equivalent of [citation needed].  But actually Wikipedia has a lot more information anyway: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slighting

Answer (score 4):

Many English verbs in the IT are not translated in the current German. For example

- scannen (to scan)
- pushen (to push)
- pullen (to pull)

Their perfekt-form should be "gescannt", "gepusht", and so on, if they would be used as regular verbs. But they are not. My current experience is that many native German speakers build a half German/half English version of the perfekt-form: "gescanned", "gepushed" and so on.

These can be considered irregular verbs, although maybe regular, but *half-English* verb would be more accurate.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to note that for most (?) German speakers there is no real difference in pronunciation between "gescannt" and "gescanned".

Answer (score 3):

I taught German at an American university and the faculty used the verb “droppen” to express the concept of dropping a class - “Wieviele haben schon gedroppt?”.

As an kind of inside joke, some of us made it (very oddly) irregular:  droppen drap gedrupt - ich droppe, du dröpst, usw. There was also a competing faction in the department that preferred “dropieren” :)

Comment: "dropieren" is schwyzerdütsch.

Comment: My experience with ad hoc "-ieren" constructions is that native speakers do not understand them, even if the meaning looks for me trivial. Maybe in Schwyz it could go better. I think the competing fraction made the same mistake, but had no native speakers to test it on.